# Nano Wi-Fi access point

Tags: wifi, access-point

I'm looking for the smallest Wi-Fi AP (access point) supporting either b, g or n.

So I'm expect to be nano/pocket size (either on battery, charge USB or being USB stick it-self). With or without support for external antenna. Price doesn't matter.

Ideally size of EP-N8531, but it's just adapter. It's mainly just for sending SSID around with some pretty much basic Wi-Fi functionality, so I could connect to it.

Comment: Should this have cellular capability (i.e. how does it connect to the internet)?  This sounds like you want a XyFi but not entirely sure based on your initial use case description

Comment: @AdamComerford XYFI sounds great, please post as an answer then. It basically can offer net via USB, SIM or as extender, doesn't matter, as long it offer something (I'm more curious towards the nano size, but the USB stick size is great). For example I was thinking more about possibility of broadcasting SSID as the way of advertisement around some places, but if it offers connection to the net, that's even cooler.

Comment: [A Raspberry PI is probably the smallest router you can feasibly get](https://jacobsalmela.com/2014/05/19/raspberry-pi-and-routing-turning-a-pi-into-a-router/)